# segmentation fault when converting (void*) to (int*)

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I Wrote a multithreaded Pthread program that outputs prime numbers. This program works as follows: The user will run the program and will enter a number on the command line. The program will then create a separate thread that outputs all the prime numbers less than or equal to the number that the user entered.
The codes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0
void* print_prime(void* arg)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *((int*)arg);//If I change it to 'temp = (int)arg',it runs well
    int flag;
    int i,j;
    for(i = 2 ; i <= temp ; i++)
    {
        flag = true;
        for(j = 2 ; j <= (int)sqrt(i) ; j++)
        {
            if(i%j == 0)
            {flag = false;break;}

        }
        if(flag == true)
            printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    if(argc != 2)
        {perror("Parameters not enough");exit(0);}
    int arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(pthread_create(&tid,&attr,print_prime,(void*)arg))
        {perror("Pthread created not successfully");exit(0);}

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

when I wrote in the terminal as:`./pthread_test 10`,a `segmentation fault(core dump)` occurs.I use `dmesg` and `addr2line -e pthread_test 0xxxxxx` to locate the error.It turns to the instruction `temp = *((int*)arg)`.
In `pthread_create(&tid,&attr,print_prime,(void*)arg)`,I have converted `arg` to a `void*` type variable,why I was wrong for using `*(int*)arg`?

Comment: In your `pthread_create` call, you're casting an `int` variable to `void*`. You have to pass `arg`'s address instead like so - `(void *)&arg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the define of function

`int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, 
         const pthread_attr_t *attr,
       void *(*start_routine) (void *), 
                         void *arg);`

the type of fourth parameter is `void*`, but in your code, you write `(void*)arg`, so this is wrong.

you can change to:

```
pthread_create(&tid,&attr,print_prime,(void*)&arg)
```

The reason, `arg` in an `int`, and the value may be `100`(just a example, your input value). If you use `(void*)arg`, that's means thay you want change `100(int type)` to `void*` type. so your code fault, because your code read the memmory address `100`. In  should pass the address of value `100` to `pthread_create`, so you need write `(void*)&arg`.

Comment: How is it wrong? Why shouldn't I do a cast from integral type to `void*`? (Yes, it's wrong, but you never say why. And I doubt you know the reason.)

Comment: That does not explain why casting any old int to pointer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you are passing the int as a pointer to void it does not alter the fact that you are sending the value of int and not its address. When you do *(int *) you are trying to obtain the content of the address(pointer to int) that you would obtain from the argument void. Obviously since you sent the value in int and not its address it will not work. Try maybe doing (void *)(&arg). But i think it is pointless castings. Why would you need to do *(int *)? Is there any particular reason? Do you understand the concept of pointer to void?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing the value

if(pthread_create(&tid,&attr,print_prime,(void*)arg))

Not the address. So you converted some value as void pointer and de-referencing it in another function. So this caused the problem.

if(pthread_create(&tid,&attr,print_prime,(void*)&arg)) is the correct one